# Help with this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

I have a person table. I also have a car table and books table.  The car and book tables both have a foreign key back to person.

I am trying to count the number of books and cars each person has. I tried:

```
SELECT 
    Person.Name, 
    COUNT(BooK.bookid) books, 
    COUNT(Car.CarId) cars 
FROM Person, Book, Car 
WHERE Person.ID = Book.PersonID = Car.PersonID
```

but I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='
```

Answer (score 16):

Some points

1. As @swasheck mentioned, you can't have a condition like `WHERE a = b = c` in SQL, it's not valid (unlike other languages). You need to make it
    `WHERE a = b AND b = c`
2. Using implict joins with `WHERE` is not good practise any more, 25 years since SQL-92 standards adopted the `JOIN` syntax (`a JOIN b ON <condition>`), which has several advantages and should be preferred. One reason is that there are several types of joins available (and all queries except those that use only `INNER` joins are hard to write using the `WHERE` syntax):

   - **`INNER JOIN`**   or just **`JOIN`**
     this is the most common type of join, combines rows from the two joined tables when they match the **`ON`**  condition.
   - **`LEFT OUTER JOIN`**  or just **`LEFT JOIN`**
     very common, too: gets all combinations of `INNER JOIN` plus all unmatched rows of the **left** table.
   - **`RIGHT OUTER JOIN`** or just **`RIGHT JOIN`**
     (not so common) the reverse of `LEFT` join: gets all combinations of `INNER JOIN` plus all unmatched rows of the **right** table.
   - **`FULL OUTER JOIN`**  or just **`FULL JOIN`**
     this is `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join, combined.
   - **`CROSS JOIN`**
   - **`NATURAL JOIN`**   and variations (not supported by SQL-Server)

   There are many references and tutorials on the Web about Joins. You can start with [MSDN online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx).
3. You also need to study how `COUNT()` works:

   - `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows (of a group).
   - `COUNT(column/expression)` counts the number of rows (of a group) where the `column` or `expression` is not null. If the `column` cannot be `NULL`, this is the same as `COUNT(*)`
   - `COUNT(DISTINCT column/expression)` counts the number of distinct values of the `column` or `expression` (within a group).

And here are a few ways to write your query:

**Option 1** - inline subqueries:

```
SELECT  
    Person.Name,  

    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Book
      WHERE PersonID = Person.ID 
    ) AS BookCount,

    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM Car
      WHERE PersonID = Person.ID 
    ) AS CarCount 
FROM 
    Person ;
```

---

**Option 2** - two `LEFT` Joins, then `GROUP BY` and use of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

This is very similar to your approach, but has the implicit joins with `WHERE` turned into explicit joins.

The `GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name` was added, too, so the query can group rows per Person.

We have to use the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in this version because the two joins may produce multiple rows per Person. (If a person has 2 Cars and 500 books, 1000 rows will be produced and then collapsed into 1 with the grouping. You can try with `COUNT(*)` there to see what (erroneous) results are produced.)

```
SELECT  
    p.Name,  
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.BookID)  AS BookCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.CarID)  AS CarCount 
FROM 
    Person AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    Book AS b 
        ON b.PersonID = p.ID 
  LEFT JOIN
    Car AS c 
        ON c.PersonID = p.ID
GROUP BY
    p.ID, p.Name ;
```

---

**Option 3** (my preference) - two `LEFT` Joins to (derived) `GROUP BY` subqueries:

```
SELECT  
    p.Name,  
    COALESCE(BookCount, 0) AS BookCount,   --- using COALESCE() so the NULLs produced
    COALESCE(CarCount, 0)  AS CarCount     --- by the (LEFT) outer joins for persons
                                           --- that have no car or no book (shame!)
                                           --- are turned into 0
FROM 
    Person AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT PersonID
           , COUNT(*) AS BookCount,
      FROM Book 
      GROUP BY PersonID
    ) AS b
        ON b.PersonID = p.ID 
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT PersonID
           , COUNT(*) AS CarCount,
      FROM Car 
      GROUP BY PersonID
    ) AS c
        ON c.PersonID = p.ID ;
```

---

**Option 4** - In SQL Server, there is also the option of using `OUTER APPLY` to (derived) `GROUP BY` subqueries. This is similar to `LEFT` joins but has even more flexibility, which can be very useful in more complex cases. (in other DBMS like PostgreSQL and DB2, the same functionality exists as well, with `LATERAL` joins).
  Notice how the `ON` conditions from option 3 have been moved to `WHERE`, inside the outer apply subqueries:

```
SELECT  
    p.Name,  
    COALESCE(BookCount, 0) AS BookCount,   --- using COALESCE() so the NULLs produced
    COALESCE(CarCount, 0)  AS CarCount     --- by the (OUTER APLY) joins for persons
                                           --- that have no car or no book (shame!)
                                           --- are turned into 0
FROM 
    Person AS p
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT PersonID
           , COUNT(*) AS BookCount,
      FROM Book
      WHERE PersonID = p.ID  
      GROUP BY PersonID
    ) AS b
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT PersonID
           , COUNT(*) AS CarCount,
      FROM Car 
      WHERE PersonID = p.ID  
      GROUP BY PersonID
    ) AS c ;
```

---

All 4 queries will give same results - all Persons and the Count of their Books and Cars, even if they have no book or no car. If you want to show only Person that have at least one Book or at least one Car (or both), options 2, 3 and 4 can be easily modified: just change the respective `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or both of them) to `INNER JOIN` - and the `OUTER APPLY` to `CROSS APPLY`.

If the problem involves calculating other aggregates, like `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc., then the options are essentially the same - but note that option 2 can be used with `MIN` and `MAX` but not with `SUM` or `AVG`. Option 1 can be used with any aggregate function but needs a separate subquery for each aggregate, so if one needs many aggregates from the same table, **options 3 and 4 are preferable**.

Answer (score 3):

What my below query does is simply isolates the different aggregrations.  In other words, I get the count of books, and then do a FULL JOIN with the count of cars (in case either subquery doesn't have a related Person).

```
select
    PersonBook.Name,
    book_count,
    car_count
from
(
    select
        p.ID,
        p.Name,
        count(b.BookID) as book_count
    from Person p
    left join Book b
    on p.ID = b.PersonID
    group by p.ID, p.Name
) PersonBook
full join
(
    select
        p.ID,
        p.Name,
        count(c.CarID) as car_count
    from Person p
    left join Car c
    on p.ID = c.PersonID
    group by p.ID, p.Name
) PersonCar
on PersonBook.ID = PersonCar.ID
```