# Calculation is not correct during in the left join table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

At the moment My head is bang on the wall as I have used few of dba.stackexchanged.com example but none of them is working.

AS I'm trying to get SKU that it sold on each Country, as I have 5 country table that it sold.

When I get results and it seems working fine, but the calculation seems wrong

One of the SKU in UK "H-ROOT-M012R-B" in return at QTY_sold_in_uk is '15552' which this calculation are wrong, the correct one is '8' which QTY has sold not '15552'

Here is a code I wrote this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u7PxDXy8kzSHV5n8VHC3rY/1
[image]

but I keep getting when I use this
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qENxYhrqhMHvUMFzYoK4ho/3

[image]

When I decided to look around and explore in the StackOverflow and I have used this link pages but results of numbers is keeping return same as the wrong one

[multiple sum query with joins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44460/how-to-create-the-multiple-sum-query-with-joins?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[second link multiple sum query with joins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016)

[MySQL Count rows from another table for each record in table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97180/mysql-count-rows-from-another-table-for-each-record-in-table)

I have used inner, left and right join or union seems that calculation is never right.
Here is DB Fiddle I has worked on it 
[Example code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qENxYhrqhMHvUMFzYoK4ho/1)

I know this code is a long one but please bear with me,

```
    SELECT 
    ti.sku,
    ti.quantity,
    -- UK
    COALESCE((suo_uk.sku), 'Not Sold') AS Unit_in_uk,
    COALESCE(sum(suo_uk.units_ordered), 0) AS QTY_sold_in_uk,

    -- De
    COALESCE((suo_de.sku), 'Not Sold') AS Unit_in_de,
    COALESCE(sum(suo_de.units_ordered), 0) AS QTY_sold_in_de,

    -- Fr
    COALESCE((suo_fr.sku), 'Not Sold') AS Unit_in_fr,
    COALESCE(sum(suo_fr.units_ordered), 0) AS QTY_sold_in_fr,

    -- ES
    COALESCE((suo_es.sku), 'Not Sold') AS Unit_in_es,
    COALESCE(sum(suo_es.units_ordered), 0) AS QTY_sold_in_es,

    -- It
    COALESCE((suo_it.sku), 'Not Sold') AS Unit_in_it,
    COALESCE(sum(suo_it.units_ordered), 0) AS QTY_sold_in_it
FROM
    tbl_inventory AS ti
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order AS suo_uk ON suo_uk.sku = ti.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order_de AS suo_de ON suo_de.sku = ti.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order_fr AS suo_fr ON suo_fr.sku = ti.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order_es AS suo_es ON suo_es.sku = ti.sku
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_sku_units_order_it AS suo_it ON suo_it.sku = ti.sku

-- where ti.sku=" H-ROOT-M012R-B"
GROUP BY ti.sku
```

Please, Advice and your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what you are actually trying to calculate, given the dataset that you have provided? The actual criteria, rather than just `QTY_sold_in_uk` should be `8`

Comment: If anyone else is looking to answer this, the problem is that `tbl_inventory` has multiple rows for each product depending on country.

Comment: Oh so if it's were you, how would you solve it problem, to avoid the multiple row, any example would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Explode-Implode" syndrome causes the inflated `SUM`.

1. The `JOINs` are done.  This gives an intermediate table with lots of rows.
2. `SUM()` and other aggregates are performed.
3. The `GROUP BY` shrinks it back down to a small number of rows.

Where practical, this is a convenient solution; note that there is no `JOIN` or `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
        ( SELECT SUM(...) ... ) AS sum_1,
        ( SELECT SUM(...) ... ) AS sum_2
    FROM ...
```

But that won't work here.  Instead, let's compute the aggregates in "derived" subqueries:

```
SELECT COALESCE(uk.qty, 0) AS QTY_sold_in_uk,
       COALESCE(de.qty, 0) AS QTY_sold_in_de,
       ...
    FROM  tbl_inventory AS ti
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, SUM(qty) AS qty ) AS uk  USING(sku)
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, SUM(qty) AS qty ) AS de  USING(sku)
```

This way, the aggregation will be confined to the the one table.  Also, the `LEFT` allows for an item not to be sold in some country, then the `COALESCE` deals with the `NULL`.  Again, no `GROUP BY`.

This pattern begs for at least 5.6 because the derived tables have no index.  However 5.6 will dynamically build one.

**Final form**

```
SELECT 
    ti.sku,
    ti.quantity,
    -- UK
    COALESCE(suo_uk.sku, 'Not Sold') AS Unit_sold_in_uk,
    COALESCE(suo_uk.units_ordered, 0) AS QTY_in_uk,
    -- De
    COALESCE(suo_de.sku, 'Not Sold') AS Unit_sold_in_de,
    COALESCE(suo_de.units_ordered, 0) AS QTY_in_de,
    -- Fr
    COALESCE(suo_fr.sku, 'Not Sold') AS Unit_sold_in_fr,
    COALESCE(suo_fr.units_ordered, 0) AS QTY_in_fr,
    -- ES
    COALESCE(suo_es.sku, 'Not Sold') AS Unit_sold_in_es,
    COALESCE(suo_es.units_ordered, 0) AS QTY_in_es,
    -- It
    COALESCE(suo_it.sku, 'Not Sold') AS Unit_sold_in_it,
    COALESCE(suo_it.units_ordered, 0) AS QTY_in_it
FROM
    tbl_inventory AS ti
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
                     FROM tbl_sku_units_order
                     GROUP BY sku ) AS suo_uk
                             ON suo_uk.sku = ti.sku
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
                     FROM tbl_sku_units_order_de
                     GROUP BY sku ) AS suo_de
                             ON suo_de.sku = ti.sku
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
                     FROM tbl_sku_units_order_es
                     GROUP BY sku ) AS suo_es
                             ON suo_es.sku = ti.sku
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
                     FROM tbl_sku_units_order_fr
                     GROUP BY sku ) AS suo_fr
                             ON suo_fr.sku = ti.sku
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sku, sum(units_ordered) as units_ordered
                     FROM tbl_sku_units_order_it
                     GROUP BY sku ) AS suo_it
                             ON suo_it.sku = ti.sku
    GROUP BY ti.sku
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good example and explanation. seems my code is "Explode-Implode" syndrome. that is a perfect word for it, I will bookmark it as a future reference. seems i need put ( bracket ) after left join

Comment: @StevenSmith - I am struggling to come up with a succinct (and generic) way to describe the syndrome.  When I succeed, I will add it to http://mysql.rjweb.org/ .