# Getting Skewed Results from LEFT OUTER JOIN with 3 TABLES

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, users (user info), mghours (volunteer time), mgtraining (training time). I want a result that lists some user columns, sum of volunteer hours and sum of two types of training:

uid lastname firstname mgstatus trainingyear vol at ce

I use the following and as long as I have the two fields from the mgtraining table and the LEFT OUTER JOIN for those in the query, I get skewed results. If I take that out of the query, my user info and vol columns are fine.

```
SELECT users.uid AS 'uid',
users.lastname AS 'lastname',
users.firstname AS 'firstname',
users.mgstatus AS 'mgstatus',
users.trainingyear AS 'trainingyear',
sum(mghours.hourstime) AS 'vol',
SUM(IF(mgtraining.trainingtype = 'AT', mgtraining.trainingtime, 0)) AS 'at',
SUM(IF(mgtraining.trainingtype = 'CE', mgtraining.trainingtime, 0)) AS 'ce'
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN mghours ON users.uid = mghours.uid AND year(mghours.hoursdate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
LEFT OUTER JOIN mgtraining ON users.uid = mgtraining.uid AND year(mgtraining.trainingdate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
WHERE users.coid = 33
GROUP BY users.uid
ORDER BY users.lastname ASC
```

The users.coid = 33 references a county ID.

I've been pouring over this for hours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 2 joins from the "master" (users) table to the 2 "details" tables (mghours and mgtraining) produces a mini cartesian product and you'll get wrong results for any user that has more than 1 related rows in each details table.

Comment: To solve the issue, you can use derived tables (where you do the group by, separately for each "details" table) and then left join `users` to these derived tables. See this answer of mine (you can skip the first paragraphs and go to Option 3): [Help with this query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016)

Comment: @ypercube I have to generate this kind of report a lot in my work and this particular DB (structure) was giving me headaches. I **was** getting a "mini-cartesian" product and was going about it all wrong. I had tried to do it with sub-queries but your reference made it much clearer. And, it worked! And fast! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`JOINs` together with aggregates (eg, `SUM()`) often give you bigger values than you expect.  To see this, remove the `SUMs` and `GROUP BY` and stare at the output.  You may see, for example, the same `mghours.hourstime` showing up multiple times.  Hence, `SUM(mghours.hourstime)` is inflated.

This is happening because `JOIN mgtraining` is coming up with multiple rows in `mgtraining` for each row in `mghours`.

The solution is to do the query in steps.  Notice how the inner query avoids inflating "vol":

```
SELECT  x.*,
        SUM(...) AS 'at
    FROM (
        SELECT  ...,
                SUM(mghours.hourstime) AS vol
            FROM ...
            GROUP BY ...
         ) x
    LEFT JOIN mgtraining ON ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...;
```