# SUM over distinct rows with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

**Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE "items" (
  "id"            SERIAL                   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "country"       VARCHAR(2)               NOT NULL,
  "created"       TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  "price"         NUMERIC(11, 2)           NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "payments" (
  "id"      SERIAL                   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "created" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  "amount"  NUMERIC(11, 2)           NOT NULL,
  "item_id" INTEGER                  NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "extras" (
  "id"      SERIAL                   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "created" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  "amount"  NUMERIC(11, 2)           NOT NULL,
  "item_id" INTEGER                  NULL
);
```

**Data**:

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES
  (1, 'CZ', '2016-11-01', 100),
  (2, 'CZ', '2016-11-02', 100),
  (3, 'PL', '2016-11-03', 20),
  (4, 'CZ', '2016-11-04', 150)
;
INSERT INTO payments VALUES
  (1, '2016-11-01', 60, 1),
  (2, '2016-11-01', 60, 1),
  (3, '2016-11-02', 100, 2),
  (4, '2016-11-03', 25, 3),
  (5, '2016-11-04', 150, 4)
;
INSERT INTO extras VALUES
  (1, '2016-11-01', 5, 1),
  (2, '2016-11-02', 1, 2),
  (3, '2016-11-03', 2, 3),
  (4, '2016-11-03', 3, 3),
  (5, '2016-11-04', 5, 4)
;
```

So, we have:

- 3 items in CZ in 1 in PL
- 370 earned in CZ and 25 in PL
- 350 cost in CZ and 20 in PL
- 11 extra earned in CZ and 5 extra earned in PL

Now I want to get answers for the following questions:

1. How many items we had last month in every country?
2. What was the total earned amount (sum of payments.amounts) in every country?
3. What was the total cost (sum of items.price) in every country?
4. What was the total extra earnings (sum of extras.amount) in every country?

With the following query ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3414/1)):

```
SELECT
  country                  AS "group_by",
  COUNT(DISTINCT items.id) AS "item_count",
  SUM(items.price)         AS "cost",
  SUM(payments.amount)     AS "earned",
  SUM(extras.amount)       AS "extra_earned"
FROM items
  LEFT OUTER JOIN payments ON (items.id = payments.item_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN extras ON (items.id = extras.item_id)
GROUP BY 1;
```

The results are wrong:

```
 group_by | item_count |  cost  | earned | extra_earned
----------+------------+--------+--------+--------------
 CZ       |          3 | 450.00 | 370.00 |        16.00
 PL       |          1 |  40.00 |  50.00 |         5.00
```

Cost and extra_earned for CZ are invalid - 450 instead of 350 and 16 instead of 11.
Cost and earned for PL are also invalid - they are doubled.

I understand, that in case of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` there will be 2 rows for item with items.id = 1 (and so on for other matches), but I don't know how to build a proper query.

**Questions**:

1. How to avoid wrong results in aggregation in queries on multiple tables?
2. What is the best way to calculate sum over distinct values (items.id in that case)?

**PostgreSQL version**: 9.6.1

Comment: See option 3 in my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016 You could also do option 4 by rewriting the `OUTER APPLY` and using `LATERAL` joins instead.

Comment: Option 3 will work but in that case it will require`Seq Scan` on payments, which means that the statistic will be recalculated on all items. I didn't mention this in the question but I want to filter items by creation time also, so I'll need only specific subset of the aggregated data. I'll update the question

Comment: *"370 earned in CZ and 25 in PL"* should be *"370 earned in CZ and **20** in PL"*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since there can be multiple `payments` and multiple `extras` per `item`, you run into a **"proxy cross join"** between those two tables. Aggregate rows per `item_id` *before* joining to `item` and it should all be correct:

```
SELECT i.country         AS group_by
     , COUNT(*)          AS item_count
     , SUM(i.price)      AS cost
     , SUM(p.sum_amount) AS earned
     , SUM(e.sum_amount) AS extra_earned
FROM  items i
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT item_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
   FROM   payments
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) p ON p.item_id = i.id
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT item_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
   FROM   extras
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e ON e.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY 1;
```

Consider the "fishmarket" example:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

To be precise, `SUM(i.price)` would be incorrect after joining to a single n-table, which multiplies each price by the number of related rows. Doing it twice just makes it worse - and also potentially computationally expensive.

Oh, and since we do not multiply rows in `items` now, we can just use the cheaper `count(*)` instead of `count(DISTINCT i.id)`. (`id` being `NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=52cd3deef188aeee7f218750419e96eb)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cb710/1)</sub>

#### But if I want to filter by `items.created`?

[Addressing your comment.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154586/sum-over-distinct-rows-in-postgresql/154603#comment295291_154603)

It depends. Can we apply the same filter to `payments.created` and `extras.created`?

If yes, then just add the filters in the subqueries as well. (Does not seem likely in this case.)

If no, but we are still selecting **most items**, the above query would still be most efficient. Some of the aggregations in the subqueries are eliminated in the joins, but that's still cheaper than more complex queries.

If no, and we are selecting a **small fraction** of items, I suggest correlated subqueries or `LATERAL` joins. Examples:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626358/939860)

Comment: That was really really helpfull!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Erwin I really like your detailed answers with examples and alternatives. +1000