# One parent 2 children sql join

Tags: join

I have 3 tables A,B,C.
A is parent of B and C.
I want to get the all A rows with sum of B and sum of c.

Ex:
table A:

```
id
1
2
3
```

table B:

```
id, parentid, data
1,  1,        12
2,  1,        23
3,  2,        24
```

table C:

```
id, parentid, data
1,  2,        44
2,  3,        23
3,  3,        24
```

what I want to get is:

```
A.id, B.sum, c.sum
1,    35,     0
2,    24,    44
3,     0,    47
```

Is it possible to get the output in single query.

Comment: Similar issue: [Help with this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query)